# Adding days to today as a UK date in PHP

Tags: php, date, format, strtotime, days

Below is a small piece of code for calculating a default delivery day from the order date (today). It all works ok and there are lots of similar questions on this subject but the date addition seems incredibly clunky  - there must be a much better way of doing this?

```
$dow_numeric = date('w');

// next delivery day from day no
switch($dow_numeric) {
case 1:                     //  order Monday
$deldays = 2;           //  deliver Wednesday (2 days)
break;
case 2:                     //  order Tuesday
$deldays = 2;           //  deliver Thursday (2 days)
break;
case 3:                     //  order Wednesday
$deldays = 2;           //  deliver Friday (2 days)
break;
case 4:                     //  order Thursday
$deldays = 5;           //  deliver Tuesday (5 days)
break;
case 5:                     //  order Friday
$deldays = 4;           //  deliver Tuesday (4 days)
break;
case 6:                     //  order Saturday
$deldays = 3;           //  deliver Tuesday (3 days)
break;
case 0:                     //  order Sunday
$deldays = 2;           //  deliver Tuesday (2 days)
break;
}

$date = date('Y-m-d');
$newdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date.' + '.$deldays.' days'));
$newukdate = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($newdate));
// test the output
echo "<br> Deliver after ".$deldays." days on the : ".$newukdate;
```

Comment: Use [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) instead. You can also get rid of most of those case statements by using a `default`. Just have specific cases for 4 5 and 6.

Comment: I would not use a switch statement for something like this in the first place, but a simple array to look up the correct value to be used in …